# Reducing number of MySQL processes

Tags: mysql, process

I need to try to understand how MySQL processes/connections work. I have googled and dont see anything in laymans terms so I'm asking here.  Here is the situation.

Our host is giving us grief over "too many MySQL processes". We are on a shared server. We are allowed .2 of the server mySQL processes - which they claim is 50 connections - and they say we are using .56.

From the technical support representative:

> "Number of MySQL procs (average) - 0.59 meant that you were using
>   0.59% of the total MySQL connections available on the shared server. The acceptable value is 0.20 which is 50 connections. "

Here is what we are running:

```
Zen Cart:           1.5.1  35K products. Auto updating of 1-20
                           products every 10 hours via cron.  
PHP version         5.3.16  
MySQL version       5.1.62-cll  
Architecture        i686  
Operating system    linux
```

We generally have about 5000 hits per day on the site and Google bot loves to visit even though I have the crawl rate set to minimum in Google webmaster tools.

I'm hoping someone can explain MySQL processes to me in terms of what this host is talking about. Every time I ask them I get an obfuscated answer that is vague and unclear. Is a new MySQL process created every time a visitor visits the site? That does not seem right.

According to the tech we were using 150 connections at that particular time.

EDIT:
here is the connection function in zencart

```
  function connect($zf_host, $zf_user, $zf_password, $zf_database, $zf_pconnect = 'false', $zp_real = false) {
$this->database = $zf_database;
$this->user = $zf_user;
$this->host = $zf_host;
$this->password = $zf_password;
$this->pConnect = $zf_pconnect;
$this->real = $zp_real;
if (!function_exists('mysql_connect')) die ('Call to undefined function: mysql_connect().  Please install the MySQL Connector for PHP');
$connectionRetry = 10;
while (!isset($this->link) || ($this->link == FALSE && $connectionRetry !=0) )
{
  $this->link = @mysql_connect($zf_host, $zf_user, $zf_password, true);
  $connectionRetry--;
}
if ($this->link) {
  if (@mysql_select_db($zf_database, $this->link)) {
    if (defined('DB_CHARSET') && version_compare(@mysql_get_server_info(), '4.1.0', '>=')) {
      @mysql_query("SET NAMES '" . DB_CHARSET . "'", $this->link);
      if (function_exists('mysql_set_charset')) {
        @mysql_set_charset(DB_CHARSET, $this->link);
      } else {
        @mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET '" . DB_CHARSET . "'", $this->link);
      }
    }
    $this->db_connected = true;
    if (getenv('TZ') && !defined('DISABLE_MYSQL_TZ_SET')) @mysql_query("SET time_zone = '" . substr_replace(date("O"),":",-2,0) . "'", $this->link);
    return true;
  } else {
    $this->set_error(mysql_errno(),mysql_error(), $zp_real);
    return false;
  }
} else {
  $this->set_error(mysql_errno(),mysql_error(), $zp_real);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are connecting? Maybe you can use connection pooling that would reduce the number of connections you have live at any one time.

Comment: `$db->connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, USE_PCONNECT, false);`  

using function connect . function connect is too long to post here. It wont let me. -------but - I really just need to try to undestand what a mysql process IS. Is that different from connection? Im trying to understand what the host is saying to me ------

Comment: Please edit a more substantial sample into your question (we can't tell from that snippet what class `$db` actually is). In the unlikely event you can't edit your question, link to a [Pastie](http://pastie.org) or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it is a problem with connection pooling. Try changing this line:

```
$this->link = @mysql_connect($zf_host, $zf_user, $zf_password, true);
```

to this:

```
$this->link = @mysql_connect($zf_host, $zf_user, $zf_password);
```

The [manual is useful here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) - the forth parameter is false by default, but your code is forcing it to be true, which creates a new connection even if an existing one is already open (this is called *connection pooling* and saves creating new connections unnecessarily i.e. saves both time and memory).

I would offer a caveat though: modifying core code in a third-party system always needs to be done carefully. There *may* be a reason for the behaviour they've chosen, though there's not much in the way of comments to be able to tell. It may be worth asking a question via their support channels to see why it works this way, and whether they might consider changing it.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. I put that this was helpful. Is that what I do to accept? Thanks again

Comment: No problems, hope it works for you. To accept an answer you like, click the tick-mark on the left of the answer :)

Comment: Don't forget that if you modify ZenCart and then upgrade it, you will probably have to re-apply your changes. So, if you can get this change accepted by the core team, or discuss it with them, that would be worthwhile.

Comment: I see you worked it out, thanks! Do please review your other questions and accept any best/good answers. Remember also you can upvote answers that are good on any question, even ones you have not asked yourself.